# Ionic Proxy and oAuth

Tags: magento, oauth, ionic-framework

I'm trying to set up this test environment, involving running the ionic server, and an apache server running Magento. I have the following setup:

- Ionic Server running on port 8100 (http://localhost:8100/#/app/home), with a proxy in the ionic.project file  to avoid any CORS issues

  "proxies": [
      {
        "path": "/magento",
        "proxyUrl": "http://www.appfactory.loc"
      }
- An apache server running on port 80, im setting a virtual host with the domain http://www.appfactory.loc/.

Everything looks find and i can see the app communicating with Magento, the problem is that Magento API is using oAuth for their API authentication, so im getting a oAuth signature invalid error, because of the proxy i set up. Any other call from magento without requiring oAuth works fine, but i still need it for the APIs. What's the best configuration to run this kind of environment?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity it's not really Magento related, its more about apache, cors, oAuth and basic environment setup, what other stackexchange sites you suggest posting this to?

Comment: Try http://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the best workflow for ionic (from my perspective) when developing with the local server, is simply to launch Chromw with the flags:

```
"\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security --user-data-dir
```

And then you can open the local html file by typing to the address bar:

```
file:///C:/stage/path-to-project/www/index.html
```

This was way simpler than using the ionic proxy.